# How to interact with sub-server through main server

Tags: web-services, web, distributed-computing, database-administration, distributed-system

I have a central server and some sub-servers. Each sub-server has a webpage. I want to access to these webpages through central server's webpage.

My current idea is: in each sub-server, implement a web service beside the webpage. The central server only need to call these services.

Another encountered issue, I place DB in the central server, sub-server have to connect to central server to get data.

My questions are:

Are there any ways to access the sub-server's webpage through central server?

If central server dies, I cannot access to sub server. I don't expect this!!!! Is there any way to place the DB.

diagram of the system: http://www.gliffy.com/go/publish/image/4963000/L.png
To reduce the traffic for the central server, APs communicate with sub-server, then central server manage these sub-server

Comment: There are many ways to access a server's web page from another server. You'll have to be more specific. Distributing a database is more properly covered on [dba.se]

Comment: Thanks, so please provide me some technique to do this. Willing to learn anything new. Ask me question if you want to have more details.

Comment: I think you missed this:"You'll have to be more specific. "

Comment: I have update the system diagram